# CallKit call block set values from array not working

Tags: objective-c, arrays, ios10, callkit

I am working on one app in which I want a feature to block call. If i am passing static values to `addBlockingEntryWithNextSequentialPhoneNumber` it's blocking numbers but when i'm passing array in `addBlockingEntryWithNextSequentialPhoneNumber` it's not blocking numbers. I have logged my array in Appdelegate and it looks fine.

Appdegate Code:

```
 NSArray *sortedArr = [lockedArr sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

[DEFAULTS setObject:sortedArr forKey:@"SortedBlockedUsers"];

NSArray<NSNumber *> *blockedPhoneNumbers = [DEFAULTS objectForKey:@"SortedBlockedUsers"];

for (NSNumber *phoneNumber in blockedPhoneNumbers) {
        NSLog(@"phoneNumber == %lld", (CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber)[phoneNumber unsignedLongLongValue]);
    }
```

output is: phoneNumber == 918849494978 phoneNumber == 919142142124

HandlerClass code:

```
NSArray<NSNumber *> *blockedPhoneNumbers = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SortedBlockedUsers"];

//NSArray<NSNumber *> *blockedPhoneNumbers = @[ @918823514521, @919586112211 ];

for (NSNumber *phoneNumber in blockedPhoneNumbers)
{
    [context addBlockingEntryWithNextSequentialPhoneNumber:(CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber)[phoneNumber unsignedLongLongValue]];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after debugging my extension class I found that problem is assigning value to array from `NSUserDefaults`. We must have to save and retrieve value using `NSUserDefaults SuiteName` to interact with Extension class.